# sorting comments data algorithm with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, comments, reply

```
const comments = [
    { 'id': 1, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 2, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 3, 'origin_id': 2 },
    { 'id': 4, 'origin_id': 2 },
    { 'id': 5, 'origin_id': 3 },
    { 'id': 6, 'origin_id': 3 },
    { 'id': 7, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 8, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 9, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 10, 'origin_id': 0 },
];

// or? data structure somthing like this? i dont konw how to use such order and depth.

const comments = [
    { 'id': 1, 'origin_id': 0, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 2, 'origin_id': 0, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 3, 'origin_id': 2, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 4, 'origin_id': 2, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 5, 'origin_id': 3, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 6, 'origin_id': 3, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 7, 'origin_id': 0, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 8, 'origin_id': 0, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 9, 'origin_id': 0, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
    { 'id': 10, 'origin_id': 0, 'reply_order': 0, 'reply_depth': 0 },
];
```

i want some algorithm something like comments in comment.
is that even possible with only that amount of data?

if someone knows any better way to implements that goals, please, tell me.

i want to concept of this. any code lang would be OK with me.
but i prefer PHP and JS.

```
const comments = [
    { 'id': 1, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 2, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 3, 'origin_id': 2 },
    { 'id': 4, 'origin_id': 2 },
    { 'id': 5, 'origin_id': 3 },
    { 'id': 6, 'origin_id': 3 },
];

// result i expected;
const result_comments = [
    { 'id': 1, 'origin_id': 0 },
    {
        'id': 2, 'origin_id': 0,
        'children': [{
            'id': 3, 'origin_id': 2, 'children': [{ 'id': 5, 'origin_id': 3 },
            { 'id': 6, 'origin_id': 3 },]
        }, { 'id': 4, 'origin_id': 2 }]
    },
];
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.
Are you asking something to do with  nested comments structure, but your example does not have nested comment, what exactly is the requirement?

Comment: What will nested sort comments result look like?

Comment: i edited my question, would you reconsider my prob? thanks for your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested object here is basically like a tree and comments become tree nodes.
first, create a dictionary with children's property and then assign the children from it.

comments id are created in ascending order, so you don't need to re-sort them after creating.

```js
// assuming that id are sorted, else you have to sort comments by id.
const comments = [
    { 'id': 1, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 2, 'origin_id': 0 },
    { 'id': 3, 'origin_id': 2 },
    { 'id': 4, 'origin_id': 2 },
    { 'id': 5, 'origin_id': 3 },
    { 'id': 6, 'origin_id': 3 },
];

// creating dictinary where key is id and value is object with added children property
let dic = comments.reduce((acc, obj) => (acc[obj.id] = {...obj, children : [] }, acc), {});

// initial set 
let treeRoot = {'id': 0, 'origin_id': 0 , children : []};

// adding in dictionary so i can add origin_id 0 to tree root
dic[treeRoot.id] = treeRoot;

// populating the childrens
comments.forEach(obj => dic[obj.origin_id].children.push(dic[obj.id]));

// if you want the array that inside treeRoot.children
console.log(treeRoot);
```